# select records with max aggregate using Linq To SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, group-by, linqpad

I have following two tables:

```
DocumentType
    Id INT,
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Active BIT,
    CreatedBy INT

Document
    Id INT,
    DocumentTypeId INT,
    Version SMALLINT,
    Text NTEXT
```

I want to select `DocumentType` and related `Document` record with maximum value for `Version`. I tried following query:

```
from t in Documents 
join tt in DocumentTypes on  t.DocumentTypeId equals tt.Id 
where tt.CreatedBy == 10
group t by t.DocumentTypeId into g
//let v = new {Version = g.Max( t => t.Version), TypeId =g.Key}
select new 
       {
           Key = g.Key, 
           Version = g.Max(t=>t.Version), 
           Text = t.Text //ERROR AT t.Text
       };
```

but it is giving me an error at following line:

```
Text = t.Text

The name 't' does not exist in the current context
```

I have tried `g.Text` also but it is not helping. Kindly help me to fix this query. I am trying this in LinqPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to retrieve a `Document` entity withing the same `DocumentType` which has the max value for the `Version` property. There is no need to group by `ntext` column.

After grouping you have groups of documents. The only thing left is to get one with the max `Version` value for each group. I'd order the group by this property in descending order, and get the first value:

```
from t in Documents
join tt in DocumentTypes on t.DocumentTypeId equals tt.Id
where tt.CreatedBy == 10
group t by t.DocumentTypeId into g
select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Version).FirstOrDefault();
```

You could project the result `Document` entity into an anonymous type if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from t in Documents 
join tt in DocumentTypes on  t.DocumentTypeId equals tt.Id 
where tt.CreatedBy == 10
orderby t.Version descending
group t by t.DocumentTypeId into g

select new 
    {
        Key      = g.Key, 
        Version  =  g.First().Version, 
        Text     =  g.First().Text 
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

`t` already stand for something else.
Try this way

```
Version = g.Max(x=>t.Version),
```

Comment: Man this is okay, the problem is coming at `Text = t.Text`. Because of grouping it expects some aggregate operator but it cannot be used on `NTEXT` type of column.